# default values(Client IP) in schema

Tags: eve

is there a way to put the client IP as default value in my schema?7

i already looked on the python-eve.org homepage in the section configuration, but i coulndt find anything ;(

thanks
Harald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `default` only accepts static values. Support for callables and lambdas is planned. Actually, at this very moment there's a pending pull request waiting to be merged.

Until then, you could probably use a callback function to achieve your payload. Something like:

```
from flask import request

def before_insert(resource_name, documents):
    if resource_name == 'myresource':
        for document in documents:
            document['field'] = request.remote_addr

app = Eve()
app.on_insert += before_insert

app.run()
```

Comment: hi nicola, thanks for your reply.. my python is really bad, can you tell me whats expected for the field 'myresource'? is this the name for my collection? best regards Harald

Comment: yes. you can filter on it if required. Alternatively you can hook your callback directly to the desired resource, just use `app.on_insert_<myresourcename>`.

Comment: hey nicola, thanks for your replay.. now i found the error.. it wasnt the collectionname.. it was the "=" there .. i need 2 of them ;-) really sorry.. i never did a line of coding in python.. so i didnt know the syntax :)